# Python - randomize value for given key and then ranzomize again if there are any repeated keys

Tags: python, pandas, random

I am using the following dict of random values:

```
dict_positionxy = {'a difficult anglethe left':{'y':random.randrange(43,54), 'x':random.randrange(0,6)},
                   'a difficult anglethe right':{'y':random.randrange(14,25), 'x':random.randrange(0,6)},
                   'long rangeN/A': {'y':random.randrange(0,68), 'x':random.randrange(40,52)},
                   'long rangethe centre':{'y':random.randrange(0,68), 'x':random.randrange(28,40)},
                   'long rangethe left': {'y':random.randrange(54,68), 'x':random.randrange(0,24)},
                   'long rangethe right':{'y':random.randrange(0,14), 'x':random.randrange(0,24)},
                   'outside the boxN/A':{'y':random.randrange(14,54), 'x':random.randrange(16,28)},
                   'penaltyN/A':{'y':random.randrange(36), 'x':random.randrange(8)},
                   'the boxthe centre':{'y':random.randrange(25,45), 'x':random.randrange(0,6)},
                   'the boxthe left':{'y':random.randrange(41,54), 'x':random.randrange(0,16)},
                   'the boxthe right':{'y':random.randrange(14,22), 'x':random.randrange(0,16)},
                   'the six yard boxthe left': {'y':random.randrange(33,43), 'x':random.randrange(4,6)},
                   'the six yard boxthe right':{'y':random.randrange(25,33), 'x':random.randrange(4,6)},
                   'very close rangeN/A':{'y':random.randrange(25,43), 'x':random.randrange(0,4)}}
```

in order to populate my X/Y grid values, like so:

```
df_temp_shots['PositionXY'] = df_temp_shots['Position'].map(dict_positionxy)
```

---

The problem is that some event keys will be repeated.

For instance if two goals have the same key 'the boxthe left' they will get the same value, which is undesired, because those will be plotted on the same spot.

---

So how do I randomize any repeated values again, always ending up with unique values within the desired range, for each key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modified solution that does not rely on `eval`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Position': ['A', 'A']})

dict_position = {'A': [[40, 60], [80, 90]]}

def dict_pos_xy(pos):
    return {'y':np.random.randint(pos[0][0], pos[0][1]), \
            'x':np.random.randint(pos[1][0], pos[1][1])}

df.Position.apply(lambda x: dict_pos_xy(dict_position.get(x)))
```

Comment: nice. I think this answer is cleaner, and `eval ` always seems a bit hacky to me.

Comment: side note. based on the structure, your proposed function should return first 'y', then 'x'. index `pos[0] ` is 'y'.

Comment: Edited, to address your comment.

Answer (score 2):

**Beware: this answer uses eval**

You can try using .apply instead. This way, it will iterate over all the rows and apply different values of random. In this solution I used `eval()`to evaluate the expressions when the value stored in the dict gets called. Notice that the values are stored as strings now.

```py
# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Position': ['A', 'A']})

dict_position = {'A': "{'x': np.random.randint(40, 60), 'y': np.random.randint(40, 60)}"}
df.Position.apply(lambda x: eval(dict_position.get(x)))
```

Which gives you the following result:

```py
    Position
0   {'x': 43, 'y': 51}
1   {'x': 48, 'y': 49}
```

Other ways could be to define a function, or to list all your conditions directly in the lambda function

Comment: thank you, but HOW would I use apply with the code above?

Comment: thank you. I get the error `TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object`

Comment: Did you edit your dict_positionxy to make all values as strings ?

Comment: oh no wait 1 min

Comment: I dont print Position with dict values here. not being applied. Ideally I would not want to replace Position items (names) with those x/y values (dicts), but rather create another column Position XY with those mapped values

Comment: Then, just add `df['PositionXY'] =` before `df.Position...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216341/discussion-between-hugolmn-and-8-bit-borges).